# Applet Works Differently when Embedded

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I am working on a game that I want to embed in a webpage. When I run the game as an Applet in IntelliJ, here's what I get:

[image]

Also note that there's a `KeyListener` and it works perfectly here.

Now, when I embed it in my website, it looks like this:

[image]

The text looks far more pixelated and the `KeyListener` doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong or is that just a property of applets? If you need any more information, just ask. Feel free to scoff quietly at the inferior graphics of this "game".

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  2) The applet probably gains focus by default when running in the applet viewer.  In a web page is a different situation.  E.G. say there are 3 versions of the same applet in one page which has links as well, what should have focus?  The first link?  The first applet?  The first applet to load?  That last applet to *finish* loading? ..

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have used KeyBindings before, so I guess I'll switch over to them. Also, the page on which I was testing had only one applet and I used the `setFocusable(true)` and `requestFocusInWindow()` methods.